# PrimeNG FullCalendar is not working and could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am currently trying to add a FullCalendar module in my Angular 7 project. I followed the steps in [this link](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fullcalendar) but without any success:

After I wrote:

```
npm install fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha.2 --save
```

and then I imported in my app.module.ts:

```
import {FullCalendarModule} from 'primeng/fullcalendar';
```

It gave me the error `Cannot find module 'primeng/fullcalendar".`

I have registered FullCalendarModule in the imports[] but it did not solve the problem.

Is there something in the documentation that I have been missing? Can you help me to add the FullCalendarModule from PrimeNG library in my project?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you only install FullCalendar? You also need to install primeng, the full setup can be found [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

Comment: Have you tried restarting the dev server after the install?

Comment: FullCalendor component not found in node module as well

Answer (score 1):

In the meantine, primeng got a major upgrade and no longer requires the old fullcalendar component. Just upgrade to 7.1.3 and follow the instruction on primeng site and fullcalendar can be easily integrated.

Comment: This worked for me. Simply remove the import in whatever module you have it in and use the CalendarModule.

Answer (score -1):

try to place FullCalendarModule on imports and exports (@NgModule) at a